# BeautifulSoup or Pandas add line break or paragrah tag to cell with multiline value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using (the very underrated) xlsx2html to convert Excel files to HTML files that I can then manipulate with Beautiful Soup for other processes. An issue I'm running into is that xlsx2html does not add line breaks to cells with multiple lines as shown in the image below.

[image: Code]

This results in an output like the below where all of the lines are on a single line:

[image: Incorrect display]

I need an output where each line is on its own line:

[image: Correct display]

I know I need to add line breaks within the cells with multiple lines, but I cannot figure out how to do that programmatically. My thought process is to search each  tag and count the number of lines of code it contains. If more than 1 line of code, add a line break (or preferably a paragraph tag). However, I cannot figure out how to count the number of lines.

I wish I had code to share what I've tried to do, but I'm at a complete blank. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, just add `<br>` to the string in spots where line doesn't end with `>\n`, but still ends with `\n`. I suck at regex so I just used `replace` in a hacky way.

Input:

[image]

Code:

```
from xlsx2html import xlsx2html
import random

in_file = xlsx2html("/path/to/your/Untitled spreadsheet.xlsx")
with open("/path/to/output_html.html", "w") as f:
    in_file.seek(0)
    v = in_file.read()
    # I suck at regex, but you can do re.sub("pattern", "<br>", v)
    # Where "pattern" selects lines that don't end with ">\n"
    hsh = str(random.getrandbits(128))
    v = v.replace(">\n", hsh)
    v = v.replace("\n", "<br>")
    v = v.replace(hsh, ">\n")
    print(v)
    f.write(v)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is great - thank you! Out of curiosity, what's the thought process behind the random and getrandbits? Just curious how I could apply that in the future.

Comment: I don't know my regular expressions well enough haha. If you're writing production code, you should use a regular expression there instead. Basically, I did what I did because my goal is to replace all "\n" with "<br>", but if I naively do that it will end up replacing the ">\n" parts too. So I temporarily replace ">\n" with a random hash as a placeholder. I use a random hash so that I don't accidentally replace actual content. And then when I'm done I 'put it back', by doing v.replace(hsh, ">\n").